# How to dynamically set textview height in Android

Tags: android, textview

In my application I need to set dynamic text to my textview so I want it to get resized dynamically. I have set:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/TextView02" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textStyle="normal"
android:text="Frontview"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:textColor="#0099CC"
android:singleLine="false"
android:maxLines="4"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
/>
```

My textview height is not going beyond 2 lines and the text is getting cut.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Konstantin said, this code will probably be ignored after you exceed 4 lines unless you remove `android:maxLines="4"`

This is how you would set the height in code:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
int height_in_pixels = tv.getLineCount() * tv.getLineHeight(); //approx height text
tv.setHeight(height_in_pixels);
```

If you want to use dip units, which allows your app to scale across multiple screen sizes, you would multiply the pixel count by the value returned by `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;`

This depends on your desired behavior, but you might also consider having the TextView size fixed, and allowing the user to scroll the text:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
tv.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: How to get dynamic value for height_in_pixels?

Comment: I edited my answer to get the approximate height of the text.  You might want to add a small buffer so that characters that hang below the line aren't cut off ("g", "y", etc).

Comment: Thanx Aaron C, but the text has disappeared after setting its height. The height is getting set to 0 despite tv not being null.

Comment: getLineCount() will return 0 if the text hasn't been rendered yet. You can call invalidate() to force a redraw, but setText() should be sufficient to make getLineCount() valid.

Answer (score 3):

```
TextView tv;
----------------------
tv=new TextView(this);   // you take TextView id (R.id.textview1)

LinearLayout.LayoutParams Params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(15,50);
tv.setLayoutParams(Params1);   //you take linearlayout and relativelayout.
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove android:maxLines="4", it restricts height of your view to 4 lines of text.

Comment: My textview height is not going beyond 2 lines and the text is getting cut.