# How to reduce the size of a text view dynamically

Tags: android, textview

I am using a textview to display a text which I am fetching dynamically. But the problem is that the size of the fetched data may vary from 10 to 30 characters. But I am using a textview with a fixed width. I can't do anything on that. Is there any way to reduce the textsize or something dynamically in order to fit it to the fixed size textview?

Comment: please provide your code of dynamically generating textview.i hope,you haven't tried with WRAP_CONTENT as a width of textview.

Comment: The textview that i am saying is in a relative layout.so if the size increases it will go out.Even if i am using WRAP_CONTENT, it looks bad.And one more thing ,the textview is not dynamically generated,the contents are dynamically generated.

Comment: But using fixed width textview is bad practice. You must adjust your layout with WRAP_CONTENT as textview width to meet your need.You have to set textview

Comment: Using fixed size component is not a good practice.instead,you should adjust other components with WRAP_CONTENT as textview width in your case.And yes,you should keep the text size in mind for text to be filled into textview and make according textview size from initial time.

Comment: I know that i can use WRAP_CONTENT, and i also know that it will wrap the contents inside that text view. But i want it to scale in that fixed size by auto decrementing the text size according to the length of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this answer, [How to dynamically set textview height android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522224/how-to-dynamically-set-textview-height-android)
It gives you idea of how to set height of textview as per number of lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextViwe txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
txt.setTextSize(Float.parseFloat(textSize));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think reducing text size according to length of the data is a bad practice. So one solution is you can move text into next line by following code.

```
textView.setSingleLine(false);
```

or

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

and set textView height as WRAP_CONTENT