# How can I dynamically change number of lines of the TextView in Android?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a `TextView` in which I have to display a large amount of text, but I don't want to show all the text, only three lines and add a button `Click to read more`, and after clicking on it all the text must expand. How I can implement this functionality and change the number of lines of the text dynamically?

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522224/how-to-dynamically-set-textview-height-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are looking for [`setLines()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLines%28int%29) method. All what you need is to register OnClickListener for Button and perform appropriate action:

```
t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
t.setLines(3);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      t.setLines(8);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TextView.setMaxLines(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMaxLines%28int%29) or [`TextView.setLines(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLines%28int%29).